# Como definir Vary for Traits para un boton en swift3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Tengo problemas para implementar un diseño para un boton, lo que estoy intenando hacer es que mi boton en la vista vertical solo muestre una imagen centrada y cuando este en horizontal este muestre una imagen y un titulo alineados a la derecha, he estado intentando usar Vary for Traits pero cuando doy el diseño a mi boton en vertical y luego en horizontal los estilos no se respetan.

Mi vista vertical se ve de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego en mi vista horizontal activo primero las Vary for traits y modifico mi boton:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que si regreso ala vista vertical, los cambios que solamente queria que se vieran en horizontal tambien se efectuaron en la otra vista:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- selecciona vary for trait en portrait
2- agrega tu boton y da estilo
3- selecciona done variyng
4- selecciona landscape orientation
5- selecciona vary for trait
6- agrega to boton y estilo
7- selecciona done variyng

Para asignar acciones a estos botonos en el ViewController donde esta el boton desde el icono amarillo arrastra hasta el ViewController destino. Asigna un identifier a el segue creado.

A los botones asignale esta accion que realizara la accion del segue:

```
   @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: “segueId”, sender: self)
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De echo asi lo tenia en un principio y si funciona, el problema es que al querer asignarle a ese boton la funcion para llamar otra vista tengo que hacerlo dos veces una vez para el boton en  vertical y otro para la vista horizontal

Comment: Como estas asignando la funcion a esos botones?

Comment: Selecciono mi boton y con el clic derecho arrastro a la siguiente vista para crear el segue, pero si uso la forma que comentas tendria que crear dos segue por cada vista, uno para mi boton horizonal y el otro vertical

Comment: En lugar de arrastrar desde el boton, arrastra de viewcontroller(el icono amarrillo en la parte superior donde esta el boton) a viewcontroller,

Comment: voy a editar para que veas el ejemplo